# symfony 3 : "this value is Not valide"

Tags: symfony

i have a problem when i insert date from calender using jquery !there is a problem of conversion i think .
II try to use

```
{{ form_widget(form.dateArrivage|date("m/d/Y") , {'attr': {'class': 'from'}}) }}<br>
```

but : 
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Symfony\Component\Form\FormView could not be converted to string

in `GestionHotelBundle:Default:index.html.twig` at line 147.

this is ReservationType

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('dateArrivage',DateTimeType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'date')
        ))
        ->add('dateSortie',DateTimeType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'date')
        ))
        ->add('nbjour')
        ->add('dateReser',DateType::class)
        ->add('chambres', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => ChambreType::class,
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ))
        ->add('save',SubmitType::class)
    ;
    ;
}
```

and this is the vue :

```
<script>
$( function() {
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
            from = $( ".from" )
                    .datepicker({
                        defaultDate: "+1w",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        numberOfMonths: 2
                    })
                    .on( "change", function() {
                        to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
                    }),
            to = $( ".to" ).datepicker({
                defaultDate: "+1w",
                changeMonth: true,
                numberOfMonths: 2
            })
                    .on( "change", function() {
                        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
                    });

    function getDate( element ) {
        var date;
        try {
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
        } catch( error ) {
            date = null;
        }

        return date;
    }
} );
```

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{  form_label(form.dateArrivage) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.dateArrivage) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.dateArrivage , {'attr': {'class': 'from'}}) }}<br>
    <br><br>
    {{  form_label(form.dateSortie) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.dateSortie) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.dateSortie, {'attr': {'class': 'to'}}) }}<br><br>
    <br><br>

{{ form_row(form.nbjour) }}
{{ form_row(form.dateReser) }}
```

Comment: You shouldn't pass a form view like `form.dateArrivage|date("m/d/Y")`, instead simply pass `form.dateArrivage`.

Comment: the same problem this value is not valid

Answer (score 2):

Doc says :

> If you want your field to be rendered as an HTML5 "date" field, you
>   have to use a single_text widget with the **yyyy-MM-dd** format (the RFC
>   3339 format) which is the default value if you use the single_text
>   widget.

So you have to change date format into your form builder:

```
$builder
        ->add('dateArrivage',DateTimeType::class, array(
            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
            'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd', //here
        ))
        ->add('dateSortie',DateTimeType::class, array(
            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
            'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd', //and here
        ))
```

Comment: the same problem : this value is not valid ! what should i put in the vue      {{ form_widget(form.dateArrivage , {'attr': {'class': 'from'}}) }}<br>

Comment: No, he can change the format if he wants. The jQuery plugin must only use the same format. Did you see my answer @O.o ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the [dateformat option](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) in the jQuery-UI datepicker :

```
$(".from").datepicker({ dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy'})
```

Nothing else. You don't need to parse the date yourself.

Other mistake you have :

DateTimeType must not use format and widget options but date_format, date_widget, time_format and time_widget options ...

Because the jQuery plugin doesn't care about time. It can only be applied on the date part.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#date-format